# Cannot add binary podDebugFramework dependency to default fat framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

So I'm trying to make a KMM project, and I want to have encrypted shared preferences.

I'm following along https://github.com/line/abc-kmm-shared-storage/tree/abb88a6952b01931825905685f9ec10cc7b86983

But I'm getting an error syncing the gradle file.

> Cannot add binary podDebugFramework dependency to default fat framework
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This fat framework already has a binary for architecture `arm64` (shared for target `ios_arm64`)

Here's my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../Mealie/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }
    val iosTarget: (String, org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosArm64
    iosTarget("ios") {
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val keychain by cinterops.creating {
                defFile(project.file("cinterop/keychain/keychain.def"))
                includeDirs(project.file("cinterop/keychain"))
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.whitewhiskywolf.mealie"
    compileSdk = 32
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}
```

And here's the script I used to generate the header

```
#! /bin/zsh
current_dir=$1
target_file_dir="$1/cinterop/keychain/"
target_file_name="Keychain.def"

rm -f "$target_file_dir$target_file_name"

echo "writing config to $target_file_dir$target_file_name"
echo "currentdir $current_dir"
mkdir -p ".$target_file_dir"

echo "->mkdir .$target_file_dir"

echo \
"language = Objective-C
headers = headers/Keychain.h headers/KeychainQuery.h
compilerOpts = -F/cinterop/keychain
linkerOpts = -F/cinterop/keychain
staticLibraries = libkeychainwrapper.a
libraryPaths = cinterop/keychain" \
>> ".$target_file_dir$target_file_name"
```

I'm just getting my bearings in KMM, so I'm not sure how this works under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adjusting the `build.gradle.kts` to the following

```
ios {
        val main by compilations.getting {
            val keychain by cinterops.creating {
                defFile(project.file("cinterop/keychain/keychain.def"))
                includeDirs(project.file("cinterop/keychain"))
            }
        }
        main.enableEndorsedLibs = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1")
                implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1")
                implementation("androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03")
                implementation("com.scottyab:secure-preferences-lib:0.1.7")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by getting {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
```

I also had to add the header files manually from the repository.